# SPAN with display block

Tags: css

What is the difference between the default `<div>` element and the default `<span>` element with `display: block`?

Answer (score 37):

There is a difference with regards to validity and semantics of HTML elements. Otherwise they are identical.

- `div` and `span` are both defined as generic containers without deeper meaning in terms of HTML. The one defaulting to block display, the other to inline, since these are the two major groups where almost any other element falls into
- Certain elements *must* be contained by an element that is defined as a block. This has nothing to do with the CSS `display` property, but with the semantics of HTML: The general idea is based on inlines being always children of blocks (which is, if you think of it, a good idea in general)
- Now, if you have a `span` with `display:block`, it will, in the sense of CSS, act exactly like a `div`. However, from the semantic point of view, if you embed block level elements inside the `span`, you are creating invalid HTML, because you nest a block in an inline element.

Comment: I believe a span marked with display block would show space characters (&nbsp) while a div would not. That would be another notable difference.

Comment: Hm, maybe I don’t fully understand what you mean, but this looks quite identical to me: https://jsbin.com/rajizul/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Nevermind, the white-space rendering will be same for anything with `display: block`. The effect I had seen appears to be specific with the use of `width: fit-content` while conditional rendering span content in React. I replaced span display block with div and it changed layout, but assumed it was a general effect. Apologies.

Answer (score 9):

- The elements that can be contained in the div or span (making a span display: block doesn't, for example, allow you to put a table inside it)
- The rendering when CSS isn't available

Comment: +1! Remember that you are not allowed to place block-elements like `<div>` inside of inline-elements (like `<span>`), as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 7):

`<span>` defaults to `display:inline;` whereas `<div>` defaults to `display:block;`

That is the only difference between the two, so if you specify `display:block;` for a span, it will act the way a div normally acts, and vice-versa.

`display:inline;` makes the element work flow in the text body, whereas `display:block;` makes it act as a block (oddly enough!).

(note there is also a less well known variant `display:inline-block;`, which is a half-way house between the two. `<img>` tags default to this setting)

Answer (score 5):

`<span>` is an inline element by default. That is the `<span>` element does not generate any breaks before and sfter ir. Also, there are some properties that cannot be applied to inline elements, like height.

`<div>` is a block level element by default. That is a `<div>` generates breaks before and after it when rendered.

You can change a block level element into inline and vice versa via the `display` property.

See [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) for an explanation of all `display` properties.

Comment: "You can change a block level element into inline and vice versa via the display property." That's not quite true - as explained in other answers, the display property only changes the formatting, but not the structure, so having a table inside would still be invalid.

Comment: can u plz explain ur line 'the display property only changes the formatting, but not the structure'. AFAIU, `display: block` gives it a `height` and `width` so it has a rectangular like structure. Since it has a structure, it affects other nearby block/structural elements.

Answer (score 3):

A `span` element with a style of `display: block` essentially becomes a `div` element.  It makes the element's width stretch to fill whatever container it is in.

Answer (score 2):

You can found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) a definition of the display CSS property.

As stated in this link, the `block` value indicates that:

> The element will generate a block box (a line break before and after the element)

By default, the value of this property is `inline` which is defined as:

> The element will generate an inline box (no line break before or after the element). This is default

Answer (score 0):

div is block element and span is inline element. There are two things that deserve attention.

1. Visible behaviour - [block formating concepts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) VS [Inline formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting)
2. (X)HTML validity relations - basicaly you never should sink block element inside inline, so if you have to create some block behaving elements structure inside a link element (which is inline) use spans and set their display:block via CSS